# Mixing GWT and Ext GWT

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I use [Ext GWT](http://www.sencha.com/products/extgwt) in my project. Why is it recommended to use a minimal amount of native GWT widgets and classes when using Ext GWT? Is it because of increases in the size of the client-side code package or some other reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't jump at the chance to use Ext GWT, because the real "danger" is future portability and maintainability concerns. The reason you'd be recommended not to mix too many native GWT widgets with Ext GWT widgets is because Ext's widgets have a different "look and feel" than their native GWT cousins. GWT uses (mostly) native HTML elements, whereas Ext GWT uses almost completely custom elements.

One example is Ext's ComboBox (left), which looks nothing like GWT's ListBox (right).

[image: Ext GWT ComboBox] vs [image: GWT ListBox]

That's on Windows. On Mac, there's even more disparity.

The CSS, though, doesn't collide. Ext GWT uses custom style names, which are prefixed by `x-` or `ext-`, whereas GWT style names begin with `gwt-`.

So my take is this: if you're looking to add some cool widgets at the expense of future portability and maintainability, go with Ext GWT. If you have any intention of potentially removing the proprietary Ext GWT stuff later, you're probably shooting yourself in the foot over a few pretty UI elements. There's hardly any concept of "just UI" with Ext stuff. You're all but forced to deeply integrate it.

For the record, I used Ext GWT for a bunch of stuff, only to later bear the pain of removing the proprietary elements later. In retrospect, I never should have done it.

Comment: I presume this comment refers to the 2.x versions of Ext GWT and not the 3.0 version (in beta as I write this)?

Comment: Separately, the problem with not using widget toolkits such as Ext GWT is that if you need a sophisticated editable, sortable, searchable, filterable, etc. Grid (table), then what do you do? Ext GWT has a very nice one, but yes, once you use it, you have to use their interfaces for loading and processing the data.

Comment: @TedM.Young I'm not speaking for any versions that aren't considered final releases. Regarding the need for sophisticated widgets: build your own. I don't recommend anyone jump on the "framework extension bandwagon". Java and GWT give you all the tools you need, it's up to you to (know how to) use them correctly. Pre-baked solutions rarely address the underlying need. There will undoubtedly someday be a time when you need something that neither GWT or Ext GWT offer. What then? Add _another_ extension? This is a classic case of lazy coding. Everyone knows which creek that attitude leads to...

Comment: With respect to "build your own", that seems like a draconian solution as the development of something like the complex grid that Ext GWT supplies is extremely expensive and requires more knowledge and skills than even expert Java developers have. So, I disagree that "Java and GWT give you all the tools you need", since they don't. Yes, if I just want a basic drop-down list, I might dress up the core GWT's widget as necessary. For complex widgets, that's simply not an option.

Answer (score 0):

EXT GWT is based on GWT and extends it by providing a beautiful set of UI elements. These elements are generated by creating custom CSS which you don't have direct access to. Whereas in the case of GWT, all Widgets are modifiable with the CSS file of the project.

So, it is not a good way to mix 2 programming languages where in the first you cannot control its CSS and in the 2nd you can do that. There might also be conflicts in case you have same style names.

Also, as this [link](http://romenlaw.blogspot.com/2009/01/problem-mixing-smartswt-and-gwt-widgets.html) says, there are some inconsistency while mixing components from different GWT extensions such as smartgwt and gwt (the same applies to extgwt and gwt)